# Submit SPARQL query with Angular 2 Typescript and AJAX

Tags: ajax, angular, typescript, sparql

I'm querying DBPedia with SPARQL. The query works fine. Now I want to get the Data from this query in my Angular 2 Project. We need to do this with AJAX. The given method looks like this: `getSPARQLTypes(): void {}` I don't know how to use SPARQL with AJAX and Typescript.

Comment: maybe the RFC helps, https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-http-rdf-update/

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435797/http-post-request-angularjs but this is for angularjs. How can I do this in angular 2?

Comment: It works like any other HTTP request via Ajax. I don't understand the problem ,there are dozens of examples on the Web.

Comment: I've tryed it with XMLHttpRequest and it works fine but how can I convert the XML request to JSON? With JSON.parse(this.responseText) i get following error: EXCEPTION: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: angular2 has an http service just like angular1, you can find the docs here . https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **Http** service provided by the framework to do it.

The request you described in the other post would look something like this.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptionsArgs, Headers, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private sparkqlData = null;
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  sparkql() {
    let headers: Headers = new Headers({
      'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    });

    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('query', 'SELECT * WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Awolnation> ?pref ?obj } LIMIT 10');
    params.append('format', 'json');

    let options: RequestOptionsArgs = {
      headers: headers,
      params: URLSearchParams
    };

    this.http.get('http://dbpedia.org/sparql', options) // 1
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.sparkqlData = data; // 3
       });
     console.log(this.sparkqlData);  // 2
  }
}
```

You can save the date to work with it later but keep in mind that the request is asynchronous and it the variable won't be filled in as you might expect.

I added comments with the order of execution of the statements.

Comment: Okay I fixed it. It works with 'Content-Type': 'application/json' and search: params. Thank you! How can I bind the response to a variable so that I can work with it?

Comment: @Lileana Are you sure that you know the typescript basics? I mean this is more than basic...any search on the Web will show you tutorials

Comment: @Lileana what do you want to do with the data? do you want to save it as a class property? I'll add that example but you have to be careful when you work with it, the **get** is asynchronous and operations might not happen in the order they are written down.